# Quarkus - logging to multiple logstashes

Tags: logging, logstash, quarkus, logback, gelf

I want to configure Quarkus app to logging to multiple logstashes. Logging should depend on current profile (dev = console, prod = logstash).

I tried to do it with gelf (https://quarkus.io/guides/centralized-log-management) but it supports only one host (quarkus.log.handler.gelf.host).

My second attempt was to use logback (quarkus-logging-logback extension) but I was unable to set different logback file for each profile. I set properties like '**logback.configurationFile**' and '**logback.configuration-file**' but nothing worked.

Do you have any ideas how to achieve this goal?

Comment: Have you tried the standard profile way, i.e. something like `%dev.quarkus.log.handler.gelf.host` to allow the dev to go and do something else?  See [here](https://quarkus.io/guides/config-reference#profiles) for more details.

Comment: @stdunbar I need more than 1 host for %prod profile, that is the problem